# how to turn off autoincrement from table args for mssql dialect

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to turn off auto increment using table args or can it only be done from the `Column()`? I am doing a bulk insert from pandas and sqlalchemy is barking at me that identity insert is not allowed when in fact I do not want auto increment being used on this table.

I was thinking there might be a mssql dialect option that would work as a qwarg so I also tried mssql_identity=False but I get an argument error  that msslq does not accept that.

```py
class PeopleTb(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'people_tb'
    PeopleID = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    PeopleName = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    __table_args__ = (
        sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint(PeopleID, name="people_tb_pk", autoincrement=False),
        {"schema": "ods"},
    )
```

Comment: You can only provide a value for an identity column if identity insert is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable IDENTITY_INSERT immediately before calling `to_sql()`:

```py
Base = declarative_base()


class PeopleTb(Base):
    __tablename__ = "people_tb"
    PeopleID = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    PeopleName = sa.Column(sa.Integer)


Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)    # for
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)  #   testing

df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 123)], columns=["PeopleID", "PeopleName"])

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT people_tb ON")
    df.to_sql("people_tb", conn, index=False, if_exists="append")
```

Comment: I like this approach.  Would I then need to set identity insert back to off?

Comment: You certainly could, and it probably would be good form to do so, although I expect that the SET IDENTITY_INSERT status is related to the database session so once the connection is closed the status would revert to the default (OFF).